# Who is that at the end of episode 2?

Tags: madoka-magica

At the end of every episode of *Puella Magi Madoka Magica* there is an artist's drawing while one of where characters is narrating the next episode preview. In Episode 2 we see this:

[image: Madoka Magica episode 2 endcar]

Who/what is that behind Homura? And why is he there?

Comment: I don't know, but probably one of the character in his works? https://www.mangaupdates.com/authors.html?id=1644 http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B0%B7%E5%B7%9D%E3%81%B8%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8B He was in charge of end card of a number of series, according to his Japanese Wikipedia article

Comment: Perhaps the creators of PMMM are really big fans of the "Road Warrior"...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, uh, this is kind of weird.

According to [a guy on Chiebukuro](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1388861238/a212338659) (which is basically Japanese Yahoo! Answers), the artist of this end card, HIKAWA Hekiru, is a fan of the movie Mad Max 2, and one of the characters in that movie is [a dude named Humungus](http://madmax.wikia.com/wiki/Lord_Humungus), who is the guy pictured here.

Also according to the guy on Chiebukuro, Humungus has apparently popped up in other works by Hikawa. I'm not familiar with any of Hikawa's works, so I don't know whether this is actually true or not, but the guy in the endcard certainly does look like Humungus.

Comment: It's been a while since i saw Mad Max 2 but yeh it does look like him. just looking at the [Anime News Network page](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/people.php?id=46869) it seems most of his works are end cards/preview illustrations though in Dusk Maiden of Amnesia i don't remember seeing Humungus in that